# How do you pronounce a ッ followed by a ー?

Tags: katakana, internet-slang

I thought I fully understood katakana, but an old meme confuses me.

Here is a nicovideo dictionary entry on it: [フタエノキワミ、アッー!](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%95%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A8%E3%83%8E%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AF%E3%83%9F%E3%80%81%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%BC%21)

If you listen to a video of the English voice actor saying it, it just sounds like a normal "aaaaaa" which I would expect to be アー.  I know アッ is already "ah", but elongating that seems impossible to me.  Why isn't it something like アーーッ?  Maybe I'm overthinking this because it's a meme, but this spelling was agreed on, so there's clearly some construct to the language that makes this normal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good point. It's actually [unpossible](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/386817055492683505/).

> 「アッ」と発声した後息を溜める所作を表現したものと思われるが、「ッ」の後に「ー」が続くという発声の不可能性からネットミームとしてウケ、やがて同性愛関係で「ア」のつく発声を表記する際に多用されるようになった。 ([source](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%BC%21))
>
> While supposed to be transcription of a gasp after uttering アッ, its impossibility of vocalization, that a ー follows a ッ, has made it viral as an internet meme, eventually becoming a popular way to transcribe ア sound in (typically the end of) a phrase with a homosexual innuendo.

And the article is also kind enough to provide a pronunciation guide:

> 文法上発音することは不可能だが、声に出して朗読する際は「アーッ！」で代用することが多く、この単語を面白がる人達は「多田野選手のみ発音ができる」とすることがある。
> 英語ではその使われ方から"aargh!"［ɑːr］という発音が一番近いと思われる。
>
> Although grammatically unpronounceable, it is usually read out as if アーッ！, or those who enjoy this word sometimes claim that only 多田野選手 (the meme origin) can pronounce it.
> In English, "aargh!"［ɑːr］might be the closest pronunciation judging from its usage.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to check for an entry on just the アッー.  I had no idea it was associated with more than just this.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 for Ralph Wiggum reference alone!